# What do these three non-terminal symbols (expr, term and factor) mean in this BNF of integer arithmetic expressions?

Tags: bnf, compiler-construction

Here is a set of standard BNF for integer arithmetic expressions, and what I want to know is how does this BNF come from？And why do we need to define the following three kinds of non-terminal symbols ("expr", "term" and "factor")?

```
expr -> term [ ('+' | '-') term ]*
term -> factor [ ('*' | '/') factor ]*
factor -> '(' expr ')' | identifier | number
```

Answer (score 4):

Technically, the names of a non-terminal don't mean anything, at least not to the parsing algorithm. Like the name of a variable in a program, their only purpose is to give the human reader some clue.

In this case, the names are mostly just a convention, loosely based on mathematical terminology. For example, if we write `3 * 7`, then we would say that 3 and 7 are factors of the result (21). There isn't really a common word for `3 + 7`, and calling them "terms" is probably easier than "summands".

The reason we split them out is that we want to describe common usage, in which `a + b * c` means "the sum of `a` and `b * c`". In other words, the argument of a "plus" or "minus" operator could be a product, but the argument of a "times" or "divide" operator cannot be a sum unless it is enclosed in parentheses. (As the grammar shows, any expression enclosed in parentheses is a "factor".)

Comment: what do you mean by " the argument of a "plus" or "minus" operator could be a product"? Can you please show me an example?

Comment: @YHSPY: I did show you an example. In `a+b*c` the arguments of the `+` are `a` and `b*c`; the second argument is a product. Note that it is not allowed to interpret that as the product of `a+b` and `c` because the argument of `*` cannot be a sum. (But it can be a parenthesized expression, so `(a+b)*c` is OK. The restriction I am talking about is syntactic, not semantic.)